# reference on complex dynamics

Tags: reference-request, gt.geometric-topology, ds.dynamical-systems, complex-dynamics, hyperbolic-dynamics

Please someone suggest me some reference on the topic "Complex Dynamics". I want a brief geometric treatment from the root level. I have graduate level background on complex analysis, riemannian geometry and topology.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

*Dynamics in One Complex Variable*. (AM-160): Third edition (Annals of Mathematics Studies) Jan 22, 2006 by John Milnor

*Complex Dynamics* (Universitext / Universitext: Tracts in Mathematics) Feb 2, 1996
by Lennart Carleson and Theodore Gamelin

*Iteration of Rational Functions*: Complex Analytic Dynamical Systems (Graduate Texts in Mathematics) Oct 1, 1991by Alan F. Beardon

*An Introduction to Chaotic Dynamical Systems*, 2nd Edition (Studies in Nonlinearity) Feb 7, 2003 by Robert Devaney

Comment: Just an update that a third edition of Devaney was published in 2021: https://www.routledge.com/An-Introduction-To-Chaotic-Dynamical-Systems/Devaney/p/book/9781032150468

Answer (score 5):

Milnor's dynamics in one complex variable seems to be a popular choice.

[Mathscinet](http://www.ams.org/mathscinet/search/publdoc.html?arg3=&co4=AND&co5=AND&co6=AND&co7=AND&dr=all&pg4=AUCN&pg5=TI&pg6=PC&pg7=ALLF&pg8=ET&review_format=html&s4=milnor&s5=complex&s6=&s7=&s8=All&vfpref=html&yearRangeFirst=&yearRangeSecond=&yrop=eq&r=1&mx-pid=2193309)

Answer (score 3):

With your background, the book by Milnor or by Beardon looks like a good choice. In addition to the references already suggested, there also are:

MR1224235 
Steinmetz, Norbert:
Rational iteration.
Complex analytic dynamical systems. de Gruyter Studies in Mathematics, 16. Walter de Gruyter & Co., Berlin, 1993. x+189 pp. ISBN: 3-11-013765-8

and

MR1747010  Morosawa, S.; Nishimura, Y.; Taniguchi, M.; Ueda, T. Holomorphic dynamics. Translated from the 1995 Japanese original and revised by the authors. Cambridge Studies in Advanced Mathematics, 66. Cambridge University Press, Cambridge, 2000. xii+338 pp. ISBN: 0-521-66258-3

(the latter also introduces some aspects of dynamics in two complex variables).